# Update table with another table based on cell value

Tags: excel, copy, cell

After searching, I understand I can copy data into a table one at a time using VLOOKUP. However, is it possible to replace an entire table with another if a cell contains a certain value?

For example,

I have a table1. I want to replace table1 with table2 if cell a1="table2"

The reason is I will have many tables and depending on what I put in a cell, A1, I want table 1 to be what ever table I choose. I also want it to be easily updated when I add even more tables.

Edit for more information:
I have one table lets call it table1. Another table, Table2, with columns Name and Values. Also I plan on having more tables, so Table3 with columns Name and Values. I have a cell somewhere on the page, or another page. If I write Table2 in this cell. I would like the entire Table1 to be replaced by table2. Ultimately copying the data in.

I have tried structured tables, but it only copies from the same row. If I put it in another row, i get null basically. Vlookup, I think requires me to have a formula for each row of the table. I might be using this formula wrong.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: And to add to @TMH8885's comment, can you provide more information on how your data are structured?

Comment: I updated the post with more information. Please let me know if i am being too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more, one solution is `INDIRECT()`.

Example workbook sheets:

- `Table1`
- `Table2`
- `Table3`

  - Assume all `Table#` tabs have the same cell range.

Make a new tab `Input`:

```
     [A]             [B]   
[1]  User Input
[2]  Table #         1
[3]  
[4]  Reference       ="'Table"&B2&"'!"
```

The formula in `B4` evaluates to `'Table1'!`.  Note that the sheet reference includes the apostophes in case the sheet name has spaces.

Make a new tab `Summary Table`:

```
     [A]
[1]  =INDIRECT(Inputs!$B$4&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))
```

This formula displays the value in the specified sheet name (from `Inputs!B4`) and the *current* row and column (so when this formula is entered in `A1`, it will display the value of `Table1!A1`). Then fill this formula across the rows and columns necessary to display the table specified in the `Input` tab.

Note of course that you could combine the `Input` and `Summary Table` tabs, but you would need to adjust the `ROW()` and/or `COLUMN()` formulas. This is also the case if your source tables do not begin in cell `A1`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there a way to combine all 3 sheets into one? I have the inputs, and summary in one page, and the tables at the bottom of this same page, named with headers.

Comment: Combining a single input cell (as in the answer) with the results table should be easy enough by just adding/subtracting to the `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` formulas as necessary. It strikes me as bad practice to include the raw data on the same worksheet, however.

Comment: The only issue is i will have so many tables, and i do not want a bunch of sheets at the bottom of the page. If you are telling me the best way is to keep them seperate, i might do just that.

Comment: Without being in your position, I can't say what is best for your specific task, but in general, I find that having multiple separate data tables on a single Excel worksheet (tab) is usually more complicated and less friendly for analytical purposes than having a single table per worksheet.

Comment: I decided to go with your method, instead i will be Hiding the tables so I won't see them once i create them. The problem now is I cannot get input and summary tables to be in one page. my summary starts at F4 and my reference is at B7. My table on another sheet starts at A1 and the data i want from it is on B2. I have 

=INDIRECT($B$7&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())).

I am not entirely sure how to adjust the formula. I apologize for making you spoon feed me...

Comment: If you put `=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())` in cell `A1`, `ROW()` = `1`, `COLUMN()` = `1`, and `ADDRESS(1,1)` = `$A$1`. Combining this with the sheet name reference in `B7` makes it return the value in `A1` on the specified sheet. If you want to display the value in `B2` from the specified sheet in cell `A1`, put `ADDRESS(ROW()+1, COLUMN()+1)` into the formula instead. Hopefully this gets you the concept you need to get it working.

Comment: Thanks! Everything works perfectly now. It ended up being ADDRESS(ROW()-2, COLUMN()-4). And I fully understand the concept now, thank you for your help!